# How can I find what part of my website is causing a browser memory leak?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I am developing a website and have noticed that when I work on the main page my browser (Firefox and Chrome) start consuming a lot of memory.

A recent example was using Firefox with 8 tabs open. 2 of which were my website. Firefox was using 800,000K (and climbing) of memory according to Windows Task Manager.

I closed down the 2 tabs pertaining to my website and Firefox memory consumption dropped to around 424,000K.

My site relies heavily on javascript (jQuery especially) and so I would suspect that my issue is coming from that direction.

Does anyone know a way of isolating what the problem is?

Thanks

Comment: you tried using firebug?

Comment: Chrome Inspector -> Profiling